# Append Characters using built-in formula while column fetch in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dml, database-optimization

I have been given a scenario that to select 4 characters from a given cell(the last 4)

I am doing it manually by using **Case** expression.
I need to automate it rather using **Cases**

I have done this.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(ticket_number) >= 4 THEN
              'x' + RIGHT(ticket_number,4)
            WHEN LEN(ticket_number) = 3 THEN 
              'x0' + ticket_number
            WHEN LEN(ticket_number) = 2 THEN 
              'x00' + ticket_number
            WHEN LEN(ticket_number) = 1 THEN 
              'x000' + ticket_number
            ELSE
              ''
        END AS ticket_number
FROM tickets
WHERE ticket_number <> ''
ORDER BY date DESC
```

I need to optimize this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
'x' + RIGHT('000'+ticket_number,4) AS ticket_number
```

If I hard-code a 2-character value:

```
SELECT 'x' + RIGHT('000'+'12',4) AS ticket_number
```

I get:

```
x0012
```

So the solution definitely works.

Comment: I don't think you need to truncate the ticket number (assuming his CASE was comprehensive, and ticket_number Max length is 4). The outer RIGHT should be enough.

Comment: On second thought, you're right.   Even if ticket_number is more than 4 characters, the outer RIGHT is enough.

Comment: For ticket_number length less then 4 its not working.

Comment: @Tab Alleman  Thanks, I was using same Length condition there. Thanks I have done It.

Answer (score 1):

select tic + REPLICATE(0,4-len(tic)) from tick

Comment: A description for even simple answers usually makes them more useful and they are generally better received.